# The HTTP verb POST used to access path '' is not allowed

Tags: html, asp-classic

This is using IIS 7.5, html and classic ASP.

I couldn't figure out the error "The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/httpdocs/sendmail_feedback.asp' is not allowed"

I have an HTML page which has a form and a submit button.

```
 <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" accesskey="s" tabindex="9" value="Submit" />
```

When the submit button is clicked, all the form fields should be sent in the form of an email using SMTP. But i keep getting this error "500 - Internal Server error". So i tried to run locally and find out the error and it happened to be "The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/httpdocs/sendmail_feedback.asp' is not allowed"

This is the code in classic asp page where an email should be sent.

```
    <%

Dim MyBody
MyBody = "The following is customer feedback from the Corporate Website Form." & vbCrLf
MyBody = MyBody & "==============================================================" & vbCrLf
MyBody = MyBody & vbCrLf
MyBody = MyBody & "Company: " & Request.Form("Company Name") & vbCrLf
MyBody = MyBody & "Name: " & Request.Form("name") & vbCrLf
MyBody = MyBody & "Phone: " & Request.Form("phone") & vbCrLf
MyBody = MyBody & "Email: " & Request.Form("email") & vbCrLf
MyBody = MyBody & "==============================================================" & vbCrLf
MyBody = MyBody & "The following comment is: "& Request.Form("comment").item & vbCrLf &vbCrLf
MyBody = MyBody & "Comments: " & Request.Form("message") & vbCrLf
MyBody = MyBody & "==============================================================" & vbCrLf




Set Mailer=CreateObject("CDO.Message")

Mailer.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtpname.com"

Mailer.Subject= request.Form("feedback_type")
Mailer.From="support@logonation.com"   
Mailer.To = "myemail@email.com"    
Mailer.TextBody= MyBody
Mailer.Send
Response.Redirect "../thankyou.html"

set Mailer=nothing
```

I hope i am clear with my problem. I just want to know where exactly am i doing wrong?!

Comment: have you specified the `Action=` part in your form tag ?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Yes i did use action= "file.asp". What else can be the problem?

Comment: Does this error occur only for this page ? Are other pages where `post` is used working ?

Comment: Happens on all the pages where i have "Post" to class asp page. :-(